# I've searched and search SwiftUI Switch Case Menu Cycle?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've found great content, But nothing too specific to my needs being swiftui is still new.
I need to support menu cycling with switch case in the latest swift and monterey for macos, no ios development. i need strings, variables, and custom graphics to make a menu title and current in need of up to 9 menus to cycle randomly from one to a random other without an if statement looping through all of the others first:
more info here: https://pastebin.com/VCnEmdBa

Additional information on needs:

I want to have the switch case cycle my nine menus, where i can be on any given one and the menu jump to the next random selection, right now it currently rotates in order no matter where i click.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Combine
import PDFKit
import SceneKit
import WebKit
 
 
struct Cotharticren: App {
  var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
  }
}
 
     struct Option: Hashable {
        
         let title: String
       
         let imageName: String
     }
 
struct ContentView: View {
 
    @State var currentOption = 0
    
    let options: [Option] = [
        .init(title: "DART Meadow", imageName: "sun.max.fill"),
        .init(title: "Research", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(title: "Navigation", imageName: "moon.stars.fill"),
        .init(title: "Shelf", imageName: "archivebox"),
        .init(title: "Chest" ,imageName: "shippingbox"),
        .init(title: "Crate" ,imageName: "bonjour"),
        .init(title: "Manufactoring", imageName: "gear"),
        .init(title: "Warehouse", imageName: "archivebox.fill"),
        .init(title: "Journal", imageName: "note.text"),
       
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
        ScrollView( .vertical) {
        NavigationView{
            /*
            List(1..<9)
            {
                     Text("\($0)")
                }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            }
 */
            ListView(options: options, currentSelection: $currentOption)
         
            //Text(systemName: myItem.selectedImageName) + Text(myItem.whateverText)
           
            switch (currentOption) {
            case 1:
                OrbitNodeView()
            case 2:
                ATM26NodeView()
            case 3:
                NozzleNodeView()
            case 4:
                EmptyView()
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Chest")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .colorInvert()
                }
            case 5:
                EmptyView()
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Crate")
               
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .colorInvert()
                }
            case 6:
                EmptyView()
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Manufactoring")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .colorInvert()
                    }
            case 7:
                EmptyView()
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Warehouse")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .colorInvert()
                        }
            case 8:
                   VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Journal")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .colorInvert()
                    .padding(.top, 60)
                       
                       Image("articrenmeadowopacity")
                           .shadow(radius: 3)
                    WebView()
                   
            }
            default:
                MainView()
           
            }
            
       }.background(Color.white)
       
        }
        
    }
        
        
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
 
 
struct MainView: View {
 
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          
              
                Image("CotharticrenMainView")
                    .shadow(radius: 3)
   
        }
            }
        
        .frame(width: 900, height: 800, alignment: .center)
 
        Spacer()
        }
       
    }
  
 
 
 
struct ListView: View {
    let options: [Option]
    @Binding var currentSelection: Int
    var body: some View{
        
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.init(red: 0.9, green: 0.95, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                   { d in d[.leading] }
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                   { d in d[.bottom] }
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color.init(red: 0.25, green: 0.9, blue: 0.2, opacity: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                            .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                               { d in d[.leading] }
                            .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                               { d in d[.bottom] }
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 1, opacity: 1), lineWidth: 2)
                .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                   { d in d[.leading] }
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.myAlignment)
                                   { d in d[.bottom] }
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                }
                }
            }
            
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
        Image("DARTMeadowCSMwidthArtemis2by1")
               
            .shadow(radius: 3)
            .padding(.top, 10)
            }
                
            
            .padding(.top, 20)
 
        
        .padding(.trailing, 10)
        }.padding(.top, 20).padding(.leading, 10)
          
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            Image("arrow300")
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("You've never plotted an Edge?")
                }
            }
            }.shadow(radius: 3)
 
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            let current = options[currentSelection]
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) {option in
                HStack {
                    
                    Image(systemName: option.imageName)
                        //.resizable()
                        //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 20)
                    
                    Text(option.title)
                        .foregroundColor(current == option ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                   
                }
                .padding(8)
                
 
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                    currentSelection += 1
                    
                    if currentSelection == 9 {
                    currentSelection = 0
                    }
              }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 800, alignment: .leading)
            
    }
        Spacer()
    }
        
}
 
 
 
 
struct WebView: View {
 
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          
              
                
   
                   
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 900, height: 800, alignment: .center)
 
        Spacer()
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: What is and is not working (what is your question) with the above code?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear i want to have the switch case cycle my nine menus, where i can be on any given one and the menu jump to the next random selection, right now it currently rotates in order no matter where i click.

Comment: I apologize but I am unable to answer your question, just ran across it in triage and was trying to help you improve it so that it would get in front of people who could.  Please put this additional information in your question description.

Comment: I've replaced your example with a minimal, reproducible version of your code.

It's much smaller now and doesn't include commented lines or Views that don't have anything to do with your problem. It runs without needing any dependencies

(edit will be live after it's been approved by another member)

Comment: It sounds like you just want a random number when the user taps try something like `currentSelection = Int.random(in: 0..<options.count)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an Identifier to your Option class and use this for `currentSelection`, if you want to set an option, just set `currentSelection` to `option.id`:

Also:
1: If you want answers, it's best to format your code, before you post it (select in Xcode and ctrl+i should do it), so it's easy to read and understand

2: A minimal, reproducible example is not just posting your entire code, create an example, that contains only as much code as necessary to show the problem you're experiencing. The code I posted would be a better example, it will work without having to change anything. Your code includes references to objects that are not on here, so a possible helper would have to remove those, before he could even test your issue

[here is a guide on how to create a minimal, reproducible example:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
struct Option: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Identifier for Option !! MUST be unique
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let imageName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentOption: Int = 0
    
    let options: [Option] = [
        .init(id: 1, title: "DART Meadow", imageName: "sun.max.fill"),
        .init(id: 2, title: "Research", imageName: "flame"),
        .init(id: 3, title: "Navigation", imageName: "moon.stars.fill"),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack {
                ListView(options: options, currentSelection: $currentOption)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width / 2, height: geo.size.height)
                switch (currentOption) {
                    case 1: Text("OrbitNodeView")
                    case 2: Text("ATM26NodeView")
                    case 3: Text("NozzleNodeView")
                    default: Text("MainView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ListView: View {
    let options: [Option]
    @Binding var currentSelection: Int
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) {option in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: option.imageName)
                        .frame(width: 20)
                    
                    Text(option.title)
                    // Don't even have to use current = options[currentSelection] anymore:
                        .foregroundColor(currentSelection == option.id ? .accentColor : .primary)
                }
                .padding(8)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // Set the currentSelection to the ID of the option
                    currentSelection = option.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I live on the Street for now and got a loan on my m1 til the 1st of October, when I get it back I will load up xcode and give it a try.

Comment: Hey :) thanks i got every thing working and i can randomly select menus from any random menu but only if running through xcode, if i close xcode and run the fresh build it cycles menus from 0-9 but i can randomly select menus if i run through xcode?

Comment: pastebin: https://pastebin.com/uBP8NVeJ

Comment: i got it working normal as you provided, i put the numbers in order for Int as 1-9 and not 0-8 aswell, cleaned build folder and ran from fresh build with xcode closed and now i can randomly be random with menu selection :) thanks :)